# Check "Run as Administrator" of shortcut file (.lnk) via vb script in windows

Tags: java, vb.net, installanywhere

Running .bat file in Windows 2008 as admin.

I have Java Application installed in Windows 2008 as user (Name of user is Test. Group of user is Admin). This application is using JSW and generating .bat file for starting application in Windows platform. This .bat file are created with help of maven plugins.

Now the problem is if I click on .bat file as normal windows user with default security settings then it does not start my application. If I start .bat file as "Run as Admin" then application starts. If I change security setting of 'Test' user and make is liberal then I can start application without running 'Run as Admin'.

I want to automate this step. I don't want user to do 'Run as Admin' or change their security settings. So I came up with solution that run some vb script after installing application by installer so that file make some security settings of that .bat file so 'Test' user can start .bat file in one step. Is this possible or any better solution ?

By the way I am using Install Anywhere for installer.

After trying for some time I figured out that I can also change setting (Advance Properties) of shortcut file which point to .bat file. This Shortcut have advance properties where there is option "Run as Administrator". If that option is checked then my issues is solved. So I was wondering is it possible to check that option in from vb script? If yes then any hints? and if not then what are alternation to do that?

I found http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ShellLink_plug-in but I do not how to do that in vb script.

Comment: Why is this tagged Java and VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do that in a batch file without prompting for password. You could make a small c++ launcher to request privileges and then run your java application.

Answer (score 0):

what version of JSW are you using?

Starting with version 3.5.7 of the JSW, it will automatically request an elevation to Administrator privileges when you start/stop a java application as Windows Service.

This is from the [JSW release notes](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/release-notes.html#3.5.7) for 3.5.7:

> Implemented a way to install, remove, start, stop, etc., the Wrapper
>   as a Windows service from a non-elevated (UAC) console. The Wrapper is
>   elevated transparently using a child process. This is needed starting
>   with Windows Vista and 2008 for smooth interaction with the Windows
>   Service Manager.

Cheers,

Comment: I am using JSW 3.2.x and I do not have option to upgrade to 3.5.7+ right now so do you have any work around ?

Comment: you can probably modify the scrip so it launches the Wrapper executable with runas http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true